# Access the value of the pair in the ArrayList

Tags: java

How can I pass the the last added element to the ArrayList and the i element in the ArrayList to the `haversineDistance` method and how can I get the lat1, lat2, long1 and long2 from them in the  `haversineDistance` method?

I want to iterate through the list to figure out whether the sender of the request is located close to one element in the list.

Test class:

```
@Path("/test")

public class Test {

    private static ArrayList<LatLong> latLongList = new ArrayList<>();

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response storeData(Data data) {

        String macD = data.getMac();
        int routeD = data.getRoute();
        float latD = data.getLatitude();
        float longD = data.getLongitude();

        // Add the lat and Long to the ArrayList.
        latLongList.add(new LatLong(latD, longD));

        int size = latLongList.size();
        if (size > 1) {

            for (int i = 0; i < latLongList.size(); i++) {

                double distance = haversineDistance(latLongList.get(i),
                        latLongList.get(latLongList.size() - 1));
                if (distance > 4) {
                    processData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        } else {

            processData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);
        }

        return Response.status(201).build();
    }

    private void processData(String macD, int routeD, float latD, float longD) {
        Database db = new Database();
        db.insertData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);
    }

    private double haversineDistance(ArrayList<LatLong> x, ArrayList<LatLong> y) {
        return 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: Is it on purpose that method `haversineDistance(...)` expects two lists of points? I thought, haversine formula computes the distance between two single points only.

Comment: @isnit2bad: I can pass the declare variable  `lat1, lat2, long1, long2` in the for lood but how I get them from the ArrayList's  element?

Comment: Again: Your method `haversineDistance(...)` has two parameters, both are lists. Is this what you want?

Comment: if it woks otherwise I want to pass the four parameter to it.

Comment: Four? I thought you want to pass two points (two objects of type LatLong)?

Comment: @isnot2bad: How can I get the latitude and longitude from the list element. I can get the element with `get(i)` but I need the  values of the pair?

Comment: As I said if it works YES

Comment: your list is a list of `LatLong`-objects, so every element you retrieve from the list with `get(i)` is such an object and contains both coordinates. So what is your problem?

Comment: Yes I know but how can I get the latitude and longitude  from it? because I am getting the complete element with `get(i)` the whole element like (lat, long) and not the lat and  long seprate so how can I reach that?

Comment: What is `LatLong`? Did you write this class? Is it from any library/API? If yes, which?

Comment: Ok I understood the  point I can get them in the haversineDistance like this  `float lat1 = x.getLatitude();`

Comment: Exactly! If `getLatitude()` is how it's named...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your method `haversineDistance` to compute the distance between **two points**, you should design the method to accept **two points**, not **two `ArrayList` of points**. As a point is represented by a `LatLong` object, you should change the method to:

```
private double haversineDistance(LatLong x, LatLong y) {
    double xLat = x.getLatitude();
    double xLng = x.getLongitude();
    double yLat = y.getLatitude();
    double yLng = y.getLongitude();

    // compute haversine distance
    double d = ...;

    return d;
}
```